# Can couchdb be installed on servers provided by nfsn?

Tags: couchdb, nearlyfreespeech

And, if it can be installed on [their](http://nearlyfreespeech.net) servers, has anyone put together a quick walkthrough for the installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, NFSN doesn't support persistent processes. Only database supported is MySQL.

Comment: Just posting to let others know that this has no longer been the case as of 2014/09/24: https://blog.nearlyfreespeech.net/2014/09/24/more-power-more-control-more-insight-less-cost/